# SumProduct inconsistencies with Syntax

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have been told that SumProduct will only work if you provide it with the same array size arguments.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]AAA 3 Year Ave Act'!$C$7:$C$15="AAA")*--('[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]AAA 3 Year Ave Act'!$BY$5:$CJ$5>=IS!D30)*--('[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]AAA 3 Year Ave Act'!$BY$5:$CJ$5>=IS!I30),'[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]AAA 3 Year Ave Act'!$BY$7:$CJ$15)
```

Yet when I use this structure, instead of returning the correct ACF value, it returns with an incorrect value. I have checked the syntax and the range it is meant to look at and I can't figure out what's causing this issue. The cells IS!D30 and I30 are dates that my sum product uses to work out which areas between those ranges it should multiply.

I have attached an image of what should be summed (This is the AAA row)
[image]

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: If `IS!D30` and `I30` are from-to dates then your comparison seems wrong. You have `$BY$5:$CJ$5>=IS!D30` and `$BY$5:$CJ$5>=IS!I30`. That means the values in `$BY$5:$CJ$5` shall be greater or equal `IS!D30` AND greater or equal `IS!I30`.

Comment: btw, you are mashing together two syntax conventions. The [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) boolean parameters can be converted to 1's and 0's with a [Double Unary](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/what-does-a-double-unary-operator-in-a-sumproduct/9fee1133-130f-4261-90b8-d32d5b885f9a) when separated by commas or by multiplying them against each other. It isn't necessary to do both.

Comment: AHHH. It was a typo mistake! Thank you for pointing that out to me @AxelRichter! For all my other SumProduct's I have <= and >= correctly but for this expression I missed it.

Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @AxelRichter - Sorry Axel, I was looking at another formula which came up with a #value error and it doesn't make sense at all. The formula being: =SUMPRODUCT(--('[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Safety Act'!$D$96:$D$105="Leadership field observations (conducted by Site Leadership Team)")*--'[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Safety Act'!$AE$5:$AP$5=IS!D31) 

The date (Jul-15) is set by a formula EOMONTH(AC5,0)+1. It then compares this to the date range IS!D31 (which is also Jul-15) but rather than producing a match - it produces 0 and I can't understand why. Could you help?

Comment: `...*--'[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Safety Act'!$AE$5:$AP$5=IS!D31` will be processed as followes: `--'[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Safety Act'!$AE$5:$AP$5` will get all values in `$AE$5:$AP$5` multiplied with `-1` and again multiplied with `-1`. If Those values are string values, this will sesult in `#VALUE` errors. You mean `...*--('[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Safety Act'!$AE$5:$AP$5=IS!D31)` this will the boolean values from the comparisons  multiply with `-1` and again multiply with `-1`.

Comment: Two notes: @Jeeped has already said that the `--` is not necessary if you already have `...(comparison resulting boolean value)*(comparison resulting boolean value)...`. And if I would be you, I would check such formulas within one sheet first. Then the cell range addresses would be not so large and the formulas easier to read.

Comment: Alternately, open the external workbook so that the XLSX file name is not displayed in the formula and temporarily rename the worksheet **w1** or something equally simple. All of the formula adjustment will be automatic and you can easily rename the worksheet back to your overly complicated name after you get the formula working. Again, the formula(s) will automatically adjust.

Comment: @AxelRichter: Hi Axel - thanks for that- i'll incorporate that for the future! However - I still can't work out why the value returned is not correct. I broke down the formula into the following to debug (before I add any more);
''UMPRODUCT(--('[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Safety Act'!$D$96:$D$105="Leadership field observations (conducted by Site Leadership Team)")' This returns a 1.0. The 2nd part however returns a 0 - however when I evaulate the formula I can clearly see the date values matching. Would you or Jeeped have any idea?

Comment: Date values will only match exactly  if they are equal up to millisecond. The values are stored as floating point `Double`. So there floating point precision takes effect. So the `=EOMONTH(AC5,0)+1` in `$AE$5:$AP$5` can result in a value which is +/-1E-09 different from 42186.000000000 in `IS!D31`. Try `=ROUND(EOMONTH(AC5,0)+1,0)` as formula in `$AE$5:$AP$5` and then `...*('[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Safety Act'!$AE$5:$AP$5=ROUND(IS!D31,0))...`.